# How to overlap linear layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using two linear layouts containing edit text in one layout and list view in  another layout. I want to show layout contains list view overlaps layout contains edittext. How to organise layouts in XML

Comment: By overlap, what do you mean? Your description is very vague...

Comment: From what I understand you should have `RelativeLayout` as parent then the above two layout as childs

Comment: Want to show list layout above the edit text layout in left side

Comment: @vignesh: Show an illustration of sorts. The OP is mighty unclear and as _Steven_ already said, very vague.

Comment: please mark it accepted answer if its really help you and solution to your question. So, it ca also help others.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to organize the layout like below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!-- Your EditText is here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!-- Your ListView is here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

With this way you got your ListView Overlaping your EditText.